# Unable to get the JSON of the Red theme. Error "Get-SPOTheme : Unknown Error"

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, pnp, theme

We need to modify some color codes for the built-in Red theme:-

[image]

So i tried running this command to get the JSON of the Red theme, but i got error:-

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Connect-SPOService -url https://***-admin.sharepoint.com 
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-SPOTheme -Name "Red" | ConvertTo-Json Get-SPOTheme 
: Unknown Error At line:1 char:1
+ Get-SPOTheme -Name "Red" | ConvertTo-Json
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-SPOTheme], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.GetSPOTheme
```

Also when i tried to get all the themses, i got nothing:-

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-SPOTheme
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

any advice ?

Comment: Might be incorrect, but I think it only returns custom themes

Comment: @RobertLindgren ok thanks for the reply ..so how i can get the JSON of the built-in theme.. as i only need to change the main color code, from been dark red to meet our red color code theme requirment.. is there a easy way to achieve this?

Comment: I guess click "Customize" do changes, and then you can save it as a custom one?

Comment: @RobertLindgren tried to click on Customize then do the changes then try to get the theme using PnP but did not work..